# Avoiding cartesian when adding unique classifier to a list in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, filter, merge, unique, cartesian-product

I have 5 .csv files I am importing and all contain emails:

```
Donors = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\am\Desktop\email parsing\Q1 2021\Donors Q1 2021 R12.csv",
                        usecols=["Email Address"])
Activists = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\am\Desktop\email parsing\Q1 2021\Activists Q1 2021 R12.csv",
                        usecols=["Email"])
Low_Level_Activists = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\am\Desktop\email parsing\Q1 2021\Low Level Activists Q1 2021 R12.csv",
                        usecols=["Email"]) 
Ambassadors = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\am\Desktop\email parsing\Q1 2021\Ambassadors Q1 2021.csv",
                        usecols=["Email Address"])
Volunteers = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\am\Desktop\email parsing\Q1 2021\Volunteers Q1 2021 R12.csv",
                        usecols=["Email Address"])
 Followers= pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\am\Desktop\email parsing\Q1 2021\Followers Q1 2021 R12.csv",
                        usecols=["Email"])
```

While I am only importing emails (annoyingly with two different naming conventions because of the systems they originate from), I am adding the import name as a classifer - i.e. Donors, Volunteers, etc.

```
Donors['Value'] = "Donors"
Activists['Value'] = "Activists"
Low_Level_Activists['Value'] = "Low_Level_Activists"
Ambassadors['Value'] = "Ambassadors"
Volunteers['Value'] = "Volunteers"
Advocates['Value'] = 'Followers'
```

I then concatenate all the files and handle the naming issue. I am sure there is a more elegant way to do this but here's what I have:

```
S1= pd.concat([Donors,Activists,Low_Level_Activists,Ambassadors,Volunteers,Advocates], ignore_index= True) 
S1['Handle'] = S1['Email Address'].where(S1['Email Address'].notnull(), S1['Email'])
S1= S1.drop(['Email','Email Address'], axis = 1)
print(S1['Handle'].count()) #checks full count
```

The total on that last line is 166,749

Here is my problem. I need to filter the emails for uniques - easy enough using .nuniques() and the but the problem I am having is I also need to carry the classifier. So if a singular email is a Donor but also an Activist, I pull both when I try to merge the unique values with the classifier.

I have been at this for many hours (and to the end of the Internet!) and can't seem to find a workable solution. I've tried dictionary for loops, merges, etc. ad infinitum. The unique email count is 165,923 (figured out via Python &/or excel:( ).

Essentially I would want to pull the earliest classifier in my list on a match. So if an email is a Donor and an Activist-> call them a Donor. Or if a email is a Volunteer and a Follower -> call them a Volunteer on one email record.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post some copy-pastable sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give it a try with some made-up data:

```py
import pandas as pd

fa = pd.DataFrame([['paul@mail.com', 'Donors'], ['max@mail.com', 'Donors']], columns=['Handle', 'Value'])
fb = pd.DataFrame([['paul@mail.com', 'Activists'], ['annie@mail.com', 'Activists']], columns=['Handle', 'Value'])
S1 = pd.concat([fa, fb])
print(S1)
```

gives

```
           Handle      Value
0   paul@mail.com     Donors
1    max@mail.com     Donors
0   paul@mail.com  Activists
1  annie@mail.com  Activists
```

You can group by `Handle` and then pick any `Value` you like, e.g. the first:

```py
for handle, group in S1.groupby('Handle'):
    print(handle, group.reset_index().loc[0, 'Value'])
```

gives

```
annie@mail.com Activists
max@mail.com Donors
paul@mail.com Donors
```

or collect all roles of a person:

```
for handle, group in S1.groupby('Handle'):
    print(handle, group.Value.unique())
```

gives

```
annie@mail.com ['Activists']
max@mail.com ['Donors']
paul@mail.com ['Donors' 'Activists']
```

Comment: That worked great. My only issue is I should have been more specific in terms of what I was looking for as end result. Specifically I want to group by the value and count the handles (deduped).  To do this I took your code and appended to a list then convert to a pd.Series then str.split on a comma I added. I am having issues "closing the deal" on grouping by the Values after deduping

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely, but if you want to count the unique emails per value, after grouping by value you can use `len(group.Handle.unique())`

Comment: Correct. So would that come after you code instead of using print? I guess you have it in the correct structure I am just unsure on how to (1) hopefully avoid using an append which slows my processing time down by alot and (2) what to do with your code if I am not printing it.

Comment: You can avoid appending by using a list comprehension, or better even create a dict on the fly, then convert that to a series: `pd.Series({value: len(group.Handle.unique()) for value, group in S1.groupby('Value')})`

Comment: That dictionary on the fly is nice but it seems like it is not grabbing the uniques for some reason. In my file, I have 166,727 emails raw and when I use this code I am getting the same number for some reason. You are right though - that dictionary on the fly is superior in terms of performance.

Comment: @Tony you mean you get duplicate email addresses?

Comment: Yes - I am getting same # before and after running dict method

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear what you need. Perhaps ask another question explain carefully? This is getting crowded.

Comment: Apologies. I will comment this 1 last time. As you point out an email could be a Donor and a Follower. When I append my lists together I get a count of Handles = 166747. Running your last piece of code I get the following output: Activists 34211, Ambassadors 124,Donors 1126, Followers 73599, Low_Level 56591, Volunteers 1096  This is exactly what I need but summing = 166747. It's the same number and I know that's not true. I think because the groupby('Value') in context of the unique handles is essentially treating handles that have two Values (i.e. Donor and Activist) as unique. Unsure of fix.

Comment: So a handle should only appear in one group? In that case you could go through the Value groups with a for loop and keep track of all handles you already encountered. Then only count those you haven't seen yet.